# Sbt dependency with non-semantic version number

Tags: dependencies, sbt

If I have code in a branch name `feature/issue-123-frobulate`, our CI system will publish a jar with a version of `issue-123-SNAPSHOT`.  Most of our code is in built with `mvn`, in which case you update the pom to have `<version>issue-123-SNAPSHOT</version>` and it pulls in branch code.

We are starting to add Scala code, built with sbt.  The relevant part of the `build.sbt` has

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.example" % "lib-being-developed" % "issue-123-SNAPSHOT",
    "com.example" % "other-lib" % "3.4.5"
)
```

where `other-lib` has a dependency on `lib-being-developed` version 2.14.0.

If I run `sbt dependencyTree`, `lib-being-developed` shows up twice, once as a direct dependency and once as a child of `other-lib`.  In both cases, the version is 2.14.0.  If I comment out the dependency on `other-lib`, `sbt dependencyTree` shows the version as `issue-123-SNAPSHOT`.

I haven't been able to find information on how `sbt` treats non-semantic versions, but it appears that in this case, `issue-123-SNAPSHOT` is considered to be a lower version than 2.14.0.

Is there a way to tell `sbt` to use the `issue-123-SNAPSHOT` version, even if there is a "higher" version used by another dependency?  I'm hoping for something like

```
   "com.example" % "lib-being-develop" % "issue-123-SNAPSHOT" :: USE_THIS_VERSION
```

I know that there is a way to exclude transitive dependencies of `other-lib`, but I would like to avoid that if I can, for several reasons.

1. This is a temporary change while everything is being developed, and we will eventually change back to `"com.example" % "lib-being-develop" % "2.14.1"`, at which point the changes to be undone are the sample place as the updates for the new version.
2. The dependency might come in several times, so I would need to figure out which dependencies are a problem and then fix all of them.

It might be possible to change the CI system to publish something like a semantic version, such as `2.14.0.issue-123-SNAPSHOT`, but that is under the control of another group, so that change involves a non-trivial amount of effort, mostly in convincing other people that it's a good idea and retraining the staff who expect the current version style.